# Corresponding last value in every minute

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

I want to extract the corresponding last value in every minute say, in a table "Table":

```
Value   Time
1     5/1/2018 15:50:57
5     5/1/2018 15:50:58
21    5/1/2018 15:51:48
22    5/1/2018 15:51:49
5     5/1/2018 15:52:58
8     5/1/2018 15:52:59
71    5/1/2018 15:53:45
33    5/1/2018 15:53:50
```

I need the corresponding last "Value" at the end of each minute in "Time". That is:

> I want the output values to be: 5, 22, 8, 33

I tried using "`as.POSIXct`" to find `Table$Time` value but I am not able to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) aggregate** Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, truncate each time to the minute and then aggregate based on that:

```
aggregate(Value ~ Minute, transform(DF, Minute = trunc(Time, "min")), tail, 1)
```

giving:

```
               Minute Value
1 2018-05-01 15:59:00     5
2 2018-05-01 16:59:00    22
3 2018-05-01 17:59:00     8
4 2018-05-01 18:59:00    33
```

**2) subset** An alternative, depending on what output you want, is to truncate the times to minutes and then remove those rows for which there are duplicate truncated times proceeding backwards from the end.

```
subset(DF, !duplicated(trunc(Time, "min"), fromLast = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
  Value                Time
2     5 2018-05-01 15:59:58
4    22 2018-05-01 16:59:49
6     8 2018-05-01 17:59:59
8    33 2018-05-01 18:59:50
```

### Note

We assume the following input shown reproducibly.  Note that we have converted the `Time` column to `POSIXct` class.

```
Lines <- "
Value Time 
1 5/1/2018 15:59:57 
5 5/1/2018 15:59:58 
21 5/1/2018 16:59:48 
22 5/1/2018 16:59:49 
5 5/1/2018 17:59:58 
8 5/1/2018 17:59:59 
71 5/1/2018 18:59:45 
33 5/1/2018 18:59:50"
Lines2 <- sub(" ", ",", trimws(readLines(textConnection(Lines))))
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines2)
DF$Time <- as.POSIXct(DF$Time, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I used the "subset" as I am able to extract information for other corresponding columns as well

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to @G.Grothendieck, but with using `format` instead, i.e.

```
aggregate(Value ~ format(Time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00'), df, tail, 1)

#  format(Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00") Value
#1               2018-05-01 15:50:00     5
#2               2018-05-01 15:51:00    22
#3               2018-05-01 15:52:00     8
#4               2018-05-01 15:53:00    33
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @ Grothendieck's great answer I provide a tidyverse solution.

```
library(dplyr)
Lines <- "
Value Time 
1 5/1/2018 15:50:57 
5 5/1/2018 15:50:58 
21 5/1/2018 16:51:48 
22 5/1/2018 16:51:49 
5 5/1/2018 17:52:58 
8 5/1/2018 17:52:59 
71 5/1/2018 18:53:45 
33 5/1/2018 18:53:50"
Lines2 <- sub(" ", ",", readLines(textConnection(Lines)))
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines2) %>% tibble::as_tibble()

# after creating reproducible data set. Set Time to date-time format
# then floor the time to nearest minute
DF %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Time = lubridate::dmy_hms(Time),
                minute = lubridate::floor_date(Time, "minute")) %>% 
# Group by minute
  dplyr::group_by(minute) %>% 

# arrange by time
  dplyr::arrange(Time) %>% 

# extract the last row in each group
  dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() == n())
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   min [4]
  Value Time                min                
  <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
1     5 2018-01-05 15:50:58 2018-01-05 15:50:00
2    22 2018-01-05 16:51:49 2018-01-05 16:51:00
3     8 2018-01-05 17:52:59 2018-01-05 17:52:00
4    33 2018-01-05 18:53:50 2018-01-05 18:53:00
```